# React IIS deployment - blank page and 404 errors on 'main...' and 'manifest.json'. How to fix this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iis, deployment

[Blank page + network tab screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhraU.png)

What I tried: I built my project in my development PC, and copied the contents of the 'build' folder to a folder in the deployment server (on-prem computer). I added the app as an Application under a website (that has other apps as well). I then gave 'IIS_IUSRS' permission to that folder. I am not using any routers in my app.

I get a blank page and 404 errors on 'main...' and 'manifest.json'.

Other React apps on the same IIS server are running just fine. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to create React application on my end and tested it by hosting it as a **new site** and as a **application** in the IIS.

I noticed that when I host it as a new website, it works fine.

When I hosted it as an application under the default site, I got the similar results as yours.

The reason is When we publish the site using the command `npm run build` it assumes that you will host it at `/` root. When you host it as an application, it is not able to find the files and showing 404 status code in the Network tab of Dev tools.

[image]

You could try adding the homepage field in the `package.json` file.

`"homepage": "http://mywebsite.com/relativepath",`

Ref: [Building for Relative Paths](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths)

**Note:** You may also need to modify other file paths in you app, so when you host it as an application, it could find the relevant files.