# Not able to host React app in Default website

Tags: reactjs, iis, localhost

I have hosted my react app on IIS using add website but when I try to add same directory into default website it dose not work .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDDbT.png)

I tried to give permission to IUSR and NETWORK_SERVICES but dosnt work

Comment: You need detailed error messages to troubleshoot the issue, try using [failed request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) to see details about 404 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Comment: Issue is partially resolved when I added "homepage" into package.json from this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75888551/react-iis-deployment-blank-page-and-404-errors-on-main-and-manifest-json/75895163#75895163 but i want more generic approach where i dont have to change homepage for each and every deployment

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.